# How to prevent tx_news plugin render single view for arbitrary news records?

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x, tx-news

I have a page with multiple news plugins. Each plugin should only render news list and single view for a given category. This is accomplished via "Single-view page for news from this category" and the TyposScript setting `detailPidDetermination`. Furthermore I have plugins with "List of selected items". This all works fine.

Now my problem: I have no clue how that could happen, but Google has now some news twice in the index. Once with the correct path to the single view and once with the path to any other plugin. This leads to duplicate content problems.

So it seems that any news plugin can render the single view for any record. Is there any way to prevent that? Especially when I use the plugin with "List of selected items", I expect it to render list and single view only for those selected records.

TYPO3 8.7
EXT:news 7.3.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only optional check is currently for the storage pid which can be enabled with `settings.detail.checkPidOfNewsRecord = 1`.

If you need further checks you need to use the signalSlot `detailAction`. However it will be very hard to know on the detail page if this news record is allowed or not as the detail view knows nothing from the list plugin.

Comment: Thx Georg! `checkPidOfNewsRecord` had escaped my notice. But I think I will try the signalSlot solution.